# infinite intersection of closed and bounded interval.

Tags: real-analysis

For each $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ let $K_n \subset \mathbb{R} $ be a closed and bounded interval, and supose that $K_1 \supseteq K_2 \supseteq K_3 \supseteq ...$
Prove that $ \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} K_n \neq \emptyset$

You may use, without proof, the fact that if K is a closed and bounded interval, and if $ (s_n) $ is a convergent sequence with $s_n \in K $ for all but finitely many n, the $ \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n \in K $

Firstly i belive that my instructor means $ \supsetneq $ not $\supseteq $ Assuming thats what this actually says is there a direct way to do this proof without taking a convergent sequence?

Comment: You probably mean $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty K_n \neq \emptyset$? This https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686748/nested-sequence-of-closed-intervals?rq=1 should answer your question.

Comment: Sorry yes .......